# if the black stone don't give benefits or harm then how come it whoever kiss get their sins forgived

Tags: hajj, contradiction

In this hadith it says  It is a stone that can neither bring about benefit nor cause harm, as ‘Umar Al-Farooq  may  Allah  be  pleased  with  him said, and it was proven in the two Saheehs [Al-Bukhari and Muslim]. but another hadith says "O Abu abdur-Rahman, why do I only see you touching these two corners?" He said: "I heard the Messenger of Allah say: 'Touching them erases sins.' And I head him say: 'whoever circumambulates seven times, it is like freeing a slave.'"
Reference    : Sunan an-Nasa'i 2919 In-book reference    : Book 24, Hadith 302 English translation : Vol. 3, Book 24, Hadith 2922 I couldn't find the hadith reference for the first one, but im confused about as if the black stone dont give any benefits nor harm then how come it forgive sins and do other benefits?

Answer (score -1):

This is reference for first hadith

> 'Umar (RAA) narrated that he kissed the Black Stone and said, ‘I know
> that you are a stone and can neither benefit anyone nor harm anyone.
> Had I not seen Allah’s Messenger(ﷺ) kissing you, I would not have
> kissed you.’ Agreed upon. https://sunnah.com/bulugh:750

> It is Allah who forgives sins And those who, having done something to
> be ashamed of, or wronged their own souls, earnestly bring Allah to
> mind, and ask for forgiveness for their sins,- **and who can forgive
> sins except Allah?**- and are never obstinate in persisting knowingly in
> (the wrong) they have done. [Quran 3:135](https://quran.com/3/135)

But Allah decides on some actions and deeds that we need to do to erase our sins. For example when we go to masjid for prayer, each step we take is reason for Allah forgiving our sin.